# How to view data for specific field in elasticsearch 2.X from URL?

Tags: elasticsearch, field

I am new to using ElasticSearch and I have a server on which elastic is running. I can only access it from the web via IP.

I did the following to view the mapping:

https://IP_ADDRESS/elasticsearch/MY_INDEX/_mapping?pretty

and got a bunch of organizational data. I was curious in one piece of data in particular, so I did the same thing, asking for a specific field:

https://IP_ADDRESS/elasticsearch/MY_INDEX/_mapping/FIELD_NAME?pretty

Now I want to actually view the data, not schema for this particular field from URL.

I tried:

https://IP_ADDRESS/elasticsearch/MY_INDEX/_search/FIELD_NAME?pretty
https://IP_ADDRESS/elasticsearch/MY_INDEX/_all/FIELD_NAME?pretty

And a few other things but nothing has worked thus far.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get, Or what is different to what you are expecting to see?

Comment: I get either no match, or I get all of the entries that _search gets me, without a filter applied. (and _search only shows a sample which does not contain what I am interested in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see a specific field from your data you need to use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#_parameters_3) like this:

```
https://IP_ADDRESS/elasticsearch/MY_INDEX/_search?pretty&_source=FIELD_NAME
                                                            ^
                                                            |
                                                        use _source
```